# Django Template view class not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am new to django, want to pass some data to my template using classed based view. for that i have used template view. but unable to get success.

**in view**

```
class MessagesSummaryView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'message_history.html'
    log_dict = {}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MessagesSummaryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT logmsg.message_id, COUNT(logmsg.log_id) AS TotalUsers, logmsg.sent_on AS Sent_ON, logmsg.log_status, msg.message_subject FROM sendmessage_log_messages logmsg, sendmessage_messages msg WHERE from_name = '"+ str(request.user.email) +"' and  logmsg.message_id = msg.message_id  GROUP BY logmsg.message_id, logmsg.sent_on, logmsg.log_status, msg.message_subject;")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        count = 0
        for row in rows:
            temp={}
            temp['message_id'] = row[0]
            temp['count'] = row[1]
            temp['Sent_ON'] = str(row[2])
            temp['message_subject'] = row[3]
            log_dict[row[0]] = temp
        context['message_history'] = self.log_dict
        return context
```

and in template

```
  <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-style-two" style="table-layout:auto; border:black solid thin;">
                <tbody>
                  <div id="content">
                    {% for contact in message_history %}
                    <tr>
                      <!--   <td style="text-align:center;">{{ contact.list_id }}</td> -->
                      <td style="text-align:left; font-size:small;  width:10%;">You Had Send Message : {{ contact.message_subject }} to {{ contact.TotalUsers }} on {{ contact.sent_on }}. <a href="/message/?message_id={{ contact.message_id}}">Show Detials</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

a lots of error has been solved, but data is not showing on the page, and one is that

```
global name 'request' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line 
`cur.execute("SELECT logmsg.message_id, COUNT(logmsg.log_id) AS TotalUsers, logmsg.sent_on AS Sent_ON, logmsg.log_status, msg.message_subject FROM sendmessage_log_messages logmsg, sendmessage_messages msg WHERE from_name = '"+ str(request.user.email) +"' and  logmsg.message_id = msg.message_id  GROUP BY logmsg.message_id, logmsg.sent_on, logmsg.log_status, msg.message_subject;")`

where you are trying to use `request.user.email`.

Try using `self.request.user.email` instead.

Comment: it works, but data is still not showing on the template page.

Comment: Try adding ``{{ message_history }}`` somewhere in your template (before the table element) to ensure that your table actually contains something (if you see ``[]`` then your table is empty and you probably need to refine your query)

Comment: yeh, data is comming in the form of nested dictionary... `{40: {'count': 2L, 'message_subject': u'Delivered', 'message_id': 40, 'Sent_ON': '2015-01-22 12:37:58.631670+00:00'}, 41: {'count': 14L, 'message_subject': u'Delivered', 'message_id': 41, 'Sent_ON': '2015-01-22 12:37:58.631670+00:00'}}`

Comment: I am accessing it like this `{% for keys in message_history %}` `{{ message_history[keys]['count'] }}`  and it sys, Could not parse the remainder: '[keys]['message_subject']' from 'message_history[keys]['message_subject']'

Comment: ``[]`` notation won't work in templates! You can only use ``.`` to access dictionary values. I recommend doing something like this: ``{% for key, val in message_history.items %} key is {{ key }} value is {{ val }} {% endfor %} `` And then you can use dots (``.``) to access properties of ``val``